# Load bunch of images with jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, load

I am making a gallery and I have about 100+ photos. It would be unwise to load them all using html src. Is there a way to load all the images with jQuery?

I have all images named "image(1)", "image(2)" etc.

I would like to do something like

```
<li><img src="image(x)"/></li>
<li><img src="image(x)"/></li>
<li><img src="image(x)"/></li>
```

etc.

Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, simply store the path to the image in the image element somewhere (not in the src attribute), then loop over them and load them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function like this

```
<div id="images"></div>

function createImages(){
    var div = $('#images');
    for (i = 1; i < 100; i++) { 
        var imgIndex = 'image(' + i + ').jpg'; // image(0).jpg;
        var src = '<img src="your path goes here.' + imgIndex+ '">';
        div.innerHTML += src;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however this doesn't work. Nothing is displayed and there is no error in de console log.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. Thanks for the help Johny!

```
function addImagetoGallery(){
        for (i = 1; i < 40; i++){
            var imgIndex = 'thumbnail ('+i+').jpg'; // image(0).jpg;
            var src = '<img src="photos/thumbnail/' + imgIndex+ '">';
            $('#imageWrapper').prepend(src);
        }

    }
```